# Compose new Outlook message with image embedded

Tags: command-line, email, microsoft-outlook

I would like to compose a new Outlook 2007 HTML message with an image embedded in the message body, with the following considerations:

- New message should be generated from the command line, so can't use Insert > Picture from Outlook
- Image should be visible in body of the new image, not attached to the email nor an attachment icon within the message body
- Message can be edited before it is sent

  I know I can compose a new message from the command line with

  outlook.exe /c ipm.note

And an image can be inserted in HTML, for example

```
<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/Img/wmd-buttons.png">
```

Can I combine these or take another approach (even a non-Outlook mail program) to compose a new message with this image visible in the body of the email? If it's not possible from the command line, can it be done with some kind of shortcut in Outlook or another application? My goal is to make it quick and easy to send an image to someone, but I have to be able to see the image in the email and add comments before I send it.

Comment: What's your Outlook version?

Comment: I am using Outlook 2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [SendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/) it's a cross-platform program to send email from the command line. It can send HTML email - it might be easiest to save your message to a file then send it like

```
sendEmail.exe -o message-file=hello.html -o message-content-type=html
```

(From, to, subject and SMTP server switches not shown)